# Running SVD and kernel busy

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am working on a movie rating recommendation model and I am trying to use the surprise module. I am able to install but when I try to run the code below I don't receive an output, it just shows kernel busy.

```
model = SVD(n_epochs=10,verbose = True)

data = Dataset.load_from_df(df2[['CustId', 'MovieId', 'Rating']], Reader())

trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3,random_state=10)

trainset = data.build_full_trainset()

model.fit(trainset)

am I missing something?

model = SVD(n_epochs=10,verbose = True)

data = Dataset.load_from_df(df2[['CustId', 'MovieId', 'Rating']], Reader())

trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3,random_state=10)

trainset = data.build_full_trainset()

model.fit(trainset)
```

I am expecting it to run but kernel shows busy